# Parsing text with bash script

Tags: bash, parsing

I want to build a bash script that reads a file and produces some command line parameters. my input file looks like

```
20.83      0.05     0.05  __adddf3
20.83      0.10     0.05  __aeabi_fadd
16.67      0.14     0.04  gaussian_smooth
8.33      0.16     0.02   __aeabi_ddiv
```

I must detect and copy all the __* strings and turncate them into a command such as

```
gprof -E __adddf3 -E __aeabi_fadd -E __aeabi_ddiv ./nameof.out
```

So far I use

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" == *__* ]] 
    then
        echo $line;
    fi
done <input.txt
```

to detect the requested lines but i guess, what i need is a one-line-command thing that i can't figure out. Any kind suggestions?

Comment: @shellter: `==` works fin with globbing.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - correct, but I assume you mean "fine".

Comment: @jordanm: I said "fin" probably because I was looking at the name of the person who edited this question. ;-)

Comment: @shellter: It means equal here, too. It's just equal to something with wildcards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r _ _ _ arg
do
    if [[ $arg == __* ]] 
    then
        args+=("-E" "$arg")
    fi
done <input.txt
gprof "${args[@]}" ./nameof.out
```

The underscores are valid variable names and serve to discard the fields you don't need.

The final line executes the command with the arguments.

You can feed the result of another command into the `while` loop by using process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r _ _ _ arg
do
    if [[ $arg == __* ]] 
    then
        args+=("-E" "$arg")
    fi
done < <(gprof some arguments filename)
gprof "${args[@]}" ./nameof.out
```

Answer (score 3):

One more way to skin the cat:

```
gprof `sed -ne '/__/s/.* / -E /p' input.txt` ./nameof.out
```

The sed script searches for lines with `__`, then changes everything up to the last space with `-E` and prints the result.  You may have to adjust things a little if your whitespace could include tabs.  For clarity, I didn't account for that here.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$4 ~/^__/{a=a" -E "$4}END{system("gprof "a" ./nameof.out")}' inputFile
```

Comment: That is perfect! I just need to turn that print into an executable command, so run instead of print.

Comment: system() instead of print is the answer! :-)

Comment: @user1431903 - don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the arrow.

Comment: @ghoti I didn't. I'm just searching for a solution without awk